# Delete all files and folder except

Tags: javascript, node.js, delete-file

My function is:

```
function Delete(dir){
    log(`[DELETE] ${dir}.`)
    fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    files.forEach(file => {
        const fileDir = path.join(dir, file);

        if (file !== 'specialfile.txt') {
           fs.rm(fileDir, { recursive:true }, (err) => {
        if(err){
        // File deletion failed
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
        }
        })
        }
    });
});
```

But he only preserves the "specialfile.txt" not the content file in case i like preserver a list of files inside in "specialfile.txt".

specialfile.txt:

```
error.dll
Windows.txt
jose.cfg
```

i need exclude all files and folder except this file content;

Comment: You need to read the content of  `specialfile.txt` and check if it includes `file` variable

Answer (score 0):

try using `fs.unlink`.
`fs.unlink` will not work on a directory, empty or otherwise.

```
fs.unlink('path/file.txt', (err) => {
   if(err) throw new Error(err);
   console.log('file is deleted.');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.